# Powershell script problem with Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, server, windows-task-scheduler

This PowerShell script, when called from Task Scheduler always sends the email which is part of True Block, even when the condition is False. Each time, when script called from Task scheduler , it will print echo "PDB_STATUS=$PDB_STATUS", which is part of False Block, but it will also send email every time.

When running the script manually from command line, it works just fine.
Cannot figure out what is the problem.

```
$env:ORACLE_SID="SID"
$env:ORACLE_HOME="D:\oracle\app\19c_home"
$env:PATH+=";D:\oracle\app\19c_home\bin"
Set-Location -Path D:\Oracle_Scripts\DB_Status

#Check PDB Status
$PDB_STATUS=
@'
set heading off
select OPEN_MODE from v$pdbs where NAME='SID';
'@ | sqlplus -s / as sysdba

#Remove Whitespace from Status Variable
$PDB_STATUS=$PDB_STATUS | select -last 2 | select -first 1

if ($PDB_STATUS -ne "READ WRITE")
{
    echo "Pluggable Database is not open for Read Write"
    $body = "Pluggable Database is not open for Read Write"
    $sender = 'oracle@'+$env:computername
    $subject = 'Database Status Alert '+$env:computername
    Send-MailMessage -From $sender -Subject $subject -SmtpServer "xx.xx.xx.xx" -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -To 'user<user@company.com>' 
}
else
{
##Log DB Status
echo "PDB_STATUS=$PDB_STATUS"
@'
set lin 300
col name for a20
select DBID,name, open_mode, to_char(open_time,'HH24:MI:SS DD-MON-YY') as open_time , to_char(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS DD-MON-YY') as NOW from v$pdbs where name='SID';
'@ | sqlplus -s / as sysdba >> DB_Status.log
}
```

Output:

```
PDB_STATUS=READ WRITE
```

Comment: The script looks fine as-is. Does it also output `"Pluggable Database is not open for Read Write"`? Could it be that your Task is targeting a different script file?  Try updating the output to something like `echo "Status GOOD, PDB_STATUS=$PDB_STATUS"`

Comment: Can you show us what is contained in `$PDB_STATUS` just before you do the `Remove Whitespace from Status Variable`? Add a `Write-Host $PDB_STATUS.GetType().FullName` there.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, Only Else block gets printed when condition is false. No True Block gets printed.
Task is pointing to correct file, i changed the output, correct output was printed.
But email is triggered every time script is executed from Task Scheduler, but script behaves fine when executed from terminal.
`PS D:\Oracle_Scripts\DB_Status> .\db_status.ps1
PDB_STATUS=READ WRITE
PS D:\Oracle_Scripts\DB_Status> .\db_status.ps1`

Comment: @Theo: 
`PS D:\Oracle_Scripts\DB_Status> echo PDB_STATUS="$PDB_STATUS"
PDB_STATUS= 

     READ WRITE

PS D:\Oracle_Scripts\DB_Status>`

Comment: No, not `echo` but `$PDB_STATUS.GetType().FullName` to see what we're dealing with. Your comment shows extra whitespace,  so if the `.GetType()` reveals it is a string, use `if ($PDB_STATUS.Trim() -ne "READ WRITE")`

Comment: Since it didn't run the rest of the `true` block, try to comment out the `Send-MailMessage`? It definitely shouldn't be running both blocks without running `if` multiple times.

Comment: @Theo: 
Write-Host $PDB_STATUS.GetType().FullName=System.Object[]  
PS D:\Oracle_Scripts\DB_Status> .\db_status.ps1  
PDB_STATUS= READ WRITE  
System.Object[]  
PDB_STATUS=READ WRITE  
PS D:\Oracle_Scripts\DB_Status

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: When commented `Send-MailMessage` didn't triggered, Else Block was executed, just as expected.
If Block is not executed, Else Block is executed, but only `Send-MailMessage` of IF True part is executed, whether condition True or False.
Problem only in Task Scheduler.

Comment: Aha, what I expected. `$PDB_STATUS` is not a single string, but an **array**, so you need to loop over the items in that collection and test each of them. Also, dig deeper and find out what that array exactly contains, **strings** or **objects**? Do `$PDB_STATUS[0].GetType().FullName` to see what the first item in the array is.

Comment: `$PDB_STATUS` is an array, I am able to remove the whitespaces and get correct value using `$PDB_STATUS=$PDB_STATUS | select -last 2 | select -first 1`.
This is all fine,
But I cannot understand/troubleshoot, even though condition is false and Else block is executed successfully, Everytime `Send-MailMessage` in IF True Block is executed only when run from Task Scheduler.

Comment: `If` doesn't loop multiple times on an array anyways. It can't be running both blocks unless the whole thing runs twice, or there's some kind of syntax error. Can you add the (trimmed) task config to your question? `Get-ScheduledTask 'task-name' | fc -Depth 2`. And how do you start it, only via schedule or manual run?